# Cucumber - Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSessionIdError using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, timeout

For a few weeks now, I've been unable to run my Ruby test automation on Chrome. I've been trying to troubleshoot the issue ever since. I keep losing connection constantly due to the error no the title, and the tests get interrupted. I saw some alternatives on the internet but none solved my problem. It works fine with Firefox. I noticed I have Chrome for Testing installed.

I installed the stable version to test and updated the chromedriver for Selenium, but it didn't fix the issue. Can you guys help me with some tips?